# How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?

Tags: android, camera, simulator

As far as i know, Android emulator doesn't have a camera. To capture a live image we have to use the web camera. I have seen code in this [web site](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source) to use the web camera in the android emulator to capture an image, but I don't know how to use this code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Download all the source files listed on the page: CameraSource, GenuineCamera, HttpCamera, SocketCamera, BitmapCamera, and WebcamBroadcaster.
2. Create a package in your project called com.tomgibara.android.camera and place the first 4 source files inside.
3. Download JMF from [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html) and install it.
4. Compile WebcamBroadcaster using the following command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_15\bin\javac.exe" -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1e\lib" WebcamBroadcaster.java     or what's equivalent to it.
5. Run it with the following command and keep it running: java "-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JMF2.1.1d\lib" WebcamBroadcaster
6. Use the following code in your program:

> ```
> CameraSource cs = new SocketCamera("192.168.0.100", 9889, 320, 240, true);
> if (!cs.open()) { 
> /* deal with failure to obtain camera */ 
> } 
> while(/*some condition*/) {   
> cs.capture(canvas) //capture the frame onto the canvas
> }
> cs.close();
> ```

PS: I haven't been able to test this because I'm getting an error when I run `WebcamBroadcaster`.

PPS: I just started experimenting with Android today so all this could be wrong.

Comment: thanks for ur response,While i m trying to create the package com.tomgibara.android.camera,i can get a error in the second file (GenuineCamera) that, no "CameraDevice" class avilable and in the third(HttpCamera) and fourth(SocketCamera) file it shows the error that,method width and height not avilable.Can u pls tell me how to clear these error.

Comment: I had the same errors and here's how to remove them: Don't include GenuindCamera in the project (just delete it) 'cause apparently, it's there to ease moving to the real camera when distributing your project (think polymorphism). And for the rest, you just need to comment the @override's in those files.

Lemme know if you have any other problems :)

BTW, did the WebcamBroadcaster work for you?

Comment: @kumar, replace `width` and `height` with `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` respectively.

Comment: I'm getting **`Unable to find a suitable player`**. What might be the problem?

Comment: ***JMF is/will be deprecated. Use JMyron instead.***