# How to overcome emulator's camera?

Tags: android, android-emulator, camera, emulation

Each time when I try to use emulator's camera in video capturing mode - I receive:

```
Sorry! The application Camera (process com.android.camera) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
```

I heard a lot of discussions around this issue, saying that emulator's camera application is buggy.

Myself tried all possible ways: used all emulators for all platforms (except honeycomb's one), tried to increase emulator heap size, tried in 32-bit and 64-bit platforms - useless. It doesn't work.

Anyway, does someone know way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera is not supported by the emulator. There's some experimental solution [here](http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source), with an SO question regarding it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image).