# Android:problem on cropping image by camera activity

Tags: android, android-camera, android-sdk-2.1

I have made an App in which I have captured an image from camera and a rectangle is shown to crop the selected area. But I'm facing two big problems in it:

1. when we change the dimensions of rectangle appeared to  large size 
   for cropping the image then instead of showing cropped image file 
   it restart camera activity?while the same thing I have done in 
   taking image  from  gallery and it is working.
2. aspect ratio is not working for image taken from camera activity?

Code for camera activity:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)
{
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true"); 
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 774);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1115);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 774);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 1115);

        if(item==0)
        {
            intent.setAction("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    }
```

Comment: actually geet i think you should go for startactivityforresult i mean when you click image you should return from the camera activity and the crop image on your old activity. just a suggestion

Comment: problem is when i open the camera its not taking the image in ratio I am  selecting

Comment: for that geet you have to override camera functionality and the giving that aspect ration in it

Answer (score 1):

check out these links

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx

http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/629.html

[How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)

http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html