# Running openCV Samples on Android Emulator

Tags: android, opencv, android-emulator, camera

I followed the instruction from openCV wiki http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package.html.

I try to run the samples on 4.0 platform. But the emulator's screen keeps black, though I can see slow process in eclipse.

I also tried on 2.2 platform, but the emulator on 2.2 cannot use my PC's webcam. So still didn't get the result

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to set up the emulator like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not support it yet, 4.0 is the latest build. It is API 14 and the link you posted says API 8, so you may have to wait til the update it.

Comment: Sorry about this confusion. I also tried on 2.2. I've edited my question