# Android: How to use webcam in emulator?

Tags: android

I'm connecting a webcam to my emulator by setting the front camera to "webcam0" in the AVD Manager.  When I start the emulator's camera application, I get the error

```
CameraService::connect X (pid 702) rejected (invalid cameraId 0).
```

Here's the relevant portion of the Android source code:

```
sp<ICamera> CameraService::connect(
    const sp<ICameraClient>& cameraClient, int cameraId) {

    int callingPid = getCallingPid();

    [...]

    if (cameraId < 0 || cameraId >= mNumberOfCameras) {
        LOGE("CameraService::connect X (pid %d) rejected (invalid cameraId %d).",
            callingPid, cameraId);
        return NULL;
    }

    [...]
}
```

The webcam has been correctly assigned an ID of 0 because there's only 1 camera. However, `mNumberOfCameras` is presumably still 0.  This means that the camera is being registered by the emulator, but it hasn't bothered to update the number of connected cameras.

**How can I connect a webcam so that it will be properly recognized by the emulator?**

Edit: the command `emulator -webcam-list -avd <name of your AVD>` in `\android-sdks\tools` gives the result:

```
List of web cameras connected to the computer:
Camera `webcam0` is connected to device `AndroidEmulatorVC0` on channel 0 using pixel format `BGR4`
```

When I launch the webcam from Eclipse's AVD manager or using `emulator -camera-front webcam0 -avd <name of your AVD>`, I get the following window:

[image]

Edit 2: This seems to be a bug in the emulator. The suggested answer tells you what to do to set up the camera, but doesn't solve the problem for me.  I ultimately solved it by using a laptop with a built-in webcam.  Perhaps another USB webcam might have worked as well.

Comment: I would suggest checking the drivers and updating them if required.

Comment: I would suggest checking the drivers and updating them if required.

Comment: My driver, despite being 6 years old, is supposedly up-to-date and I can't find a newer version online.  I may try changing cameras if I can find another.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

UPDATE

In Android Studio AVD:

1. Open AVD Manager:

[image: AVD menu]

2. Add/Edit AVD:

[image: Specific AVD strip]

3. Click Advanced Settings in the bottom of the screen:

[image: AVD Advanced Settings]

4. Set your camera of choice as the front/back cameras:

[image: AVD Camera Settings]

Comment: You should't set the front and back camera's to the same source.

Comment: @ChrisRiver Why not? It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Cool! But how to change webcam if we have more than one?

Comment: If the Camera app crashes with the error "Can't connect to the camera", try rebooting the emulated device and clearing the Camera's app's cache & data. This worked for me.

Comment: Sometimes it is helpful to set front and back camera's to same source, like when Camera isn't recognizing a webcam as a valid input source (i.e. when it only shows the other source and doesn't let you invert to the other camera)

Comment: It instantly crashes simulator when the camera starts. I'm on a mac.

Comment: @MilindMevada, after a few days and a few laptop restarts, I noticed it works, and my face/ webcam feed is showing live on the emulator, sideways though.

Comment: ok thanks. I had a permission issue that's why it was crashing.

Comment: @walkmn You can use alternate cam via the CLI: `cd "${ANDROID_HOME}/tools"; ./emulator -avd $VIRTUAL_DEVICE_AVD_ID -camera-back webcam1`

Comment: @MilindMevada make sure you allow the android emulator to use your mac hardware camera - if you didn't allow in the prompt on first try, you can set it in the privacy settings of your mac in system preferences. thanks for the highlight.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832637/android-studios-emulator-has-an-error-cant-connect-to-camera/36904976 which fixed the follow-up error for me

Comment: Attention!!! : the front and back cameras should not be the same!!!

Answer (score 48):

Follow the below steps in Eclipse.

1. Goto -> AVD Manager
2. Create/Edit the AVD.
3. Hardware > New:
4. Configures camera facing back
5. Click on the property value and choose = "webcam0".
6. Once done all the above the webcam should be connected. If it doesnt then you need to check your WebCam drivers.

Check here for more information :
[How to use web camera in android emulator to capture a live image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image)

[image]

Comment: I think this is an older UI for the AVD manager.  I used to have a window that looked like this, but now I can select the front and rear cameras from dedicated drop-down menus.

Comment: I use a mac so eclipse looks this way in mac osx. So the windows and menus might be different in Microsoft windows and linux os.

Comment: Note that you also need to choose correct API. You can choose emulation for API 10 but it won't work. I think API 16 was the first to really support it.

Comment: No the emulation is based on ADT and not on Android API. ADT supports emulation since 19 I think.

Comment: In the Android Studio, for the step 3 select the "Show Advanced Settings" button to display the camera options.

Answer (score 6):

## On macOS

### Explanation

Adding to [@nurnachman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403717/nurnachman)'s [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792615/5953643), on macOS you'll also need to grant the emulator elevated permissions by launching it from the Terminal using `sudo`.

### Steps

#### 1. Use the Android Device Manager to set the Camera settings to `Webcam0`

> UPDATE
>
> In Android Studio AVD:
>
> 1. Open AVD Manager:
>
> [image: AVD menu]
>
> 2. Add/Edit AVD:
>
> [image: Specific AVD strip]
>
> 3. Click Advanced Settings in the bottom of the screen:
>
> [image: AVD Advanced Settings]
>
> 4. Set your camera of choice as the front/back cameras:
>
> [image: AVD Camera Settings]

#### 2. Launch the [macOS Terminal](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjunOCZm-P8AhVSrIQIHX60AikQFnoECBEQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.apple.com%2Fguide%2Fterminal%2Fopen-or-quit-terminal-apd5265185d-f365-44cb-8b09-71a064a42125%2Fmac&usg=AOvVaw38yunYqFSDSP2S9Bs-zTTX)

#### 3. In the Terminal, enter the following command to list the names of your installed Android Emulators

Emulators Installed via Android Studio:

```bash
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -list-avds
```

Emulators Installed via Visual Studio for Mac:

```bash
~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/emulator emulator -list-avds
```

#### 4. Launch the Android Emulator with elevated privileges:

Emulators Installed via Android Studio:

```bash
sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd [Your Emulator Name]
```

> **Note:** Replace `[Your Emulator Name]` with the name of your emulator discovered in Step 3
>
> e.g. `sudo ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd pixel_5_-api_33`

Emulators Installed via Visual Studio for Mac:

```bash
~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/emulator -avd [Your Emulator Name]
```

> **Note:** Replace `[Your Emulator Name]` with the name of your emulator discovered in Step 3
>
> e.g. `sudo ~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx/emulator -avd pixel_5_-api_33`

#### 5. When the Emulator launches and when your app access the Camera, accept macOS request to grant Camera permissions

---

## Troubleshooting

### Ensure Camera Permission Enabled for Terminal

If the Android Camera is still not working after launching it with elevated permissions via the Terminal, in [System Settings.app](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-system-settings-mh15217/mac), navigate to `Privacy & Security` -> `Camera` and ensure the Camera Permission for `Terminal` is enabled

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see terminal in this Camera permission tab

Comment: @hannesach The option won't appear in System Settings under the Camera's Permissions tab until you've set the Android Emulator to use `webcom0`, then used Terminal to launch the Android Emulator and subsequently launch the camera on the Android Emulator. 

The steps to accomplish this are all listed above.

Comment: I use MacOS Venture 13.1, I set Android Emulator to use `webcom0` but I never see terminal in System settings. That's why I'm asking

Comment: @hannesach Yes. You must first launch the Emulator from the terminal with elevated privileges (sudo) as described in the steps above. I can confirm the above steps work on macOS 13.1.

Comment: I did a start from terminal as well `~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd API_30_Google_Api -camera-front webcam0`same with all combinations of `-camera-back`, `-camera-front`, `webcam1` and `webcam0`. Even when I set it in UI settings. It never recognize a camera and I'm never asked from MacOS. So it must be something else. Btw, I use a Apple Silicon M1

Comment: I followed the instructions in the answer on this post (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360851/add-access-to-the-macbook-camera-for-the-terminal-application) to force a permissions request for camera for terminal.

Comment: On macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 (M2 chip) emulator crashes every time when I start the built-in camera app (Android 13 Google API image). All 5 steps succeeded and Terminal has camera permission. Any suggestions?

Comment: Camera crashes emulator on macOS Sonoma! Beware of this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/302562962?pli=1 before updating to Sonoma! Lucky me :/