# Using Laptop Webcam as Android Emulator's Cameta

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to use my laptop webcam as my back camera of my emulator for sdk version 10 and 16, but in both case the emulator does not found my webcam though the emulator does not show any shortage of SD cart memory or also request permission for using webcam. When I run emulator's default camera app, it shows grid of gray and black with a greed rectangle moving here and there, when capturing photos it capture the same thing at that time on screen. Can anyone give me any solution please. My complete emulator configuration is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This link can be helpful [Android: How to use webcam in emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012924/android-how-to-use-webcam-in-emulator)

Short story is:

1. Go to AVD manager
2. Select your device
3. Go to device properties
4. Change back facing camera dropdown value to "webcam0"

If it all not working you can try to use genymotion emulator http://www.genymotion.com/

It works much more faster and it easy to use your laptop webcam as back camera of the device