# Android: Error using webcam in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, webcam

In [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012924/android-how-to-use-webcam-in-emulator), I got this error when starting the camera application in an emulator with a webcam connected:

```
CameraService::connect X (pid 702) rejected (invalid cameraId 0).
```

After updating the dev tools, I got this other error instead (then, after making a new emulator, I got the first error again):

```
03-15 03:44:04.272: E/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(40): queryStart: Query failed: Cannot start the camera
03-15 03:44:04.272: E/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(40): startDevice: Unable to start device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' for NV21[640x480] frames
```

[...]

```
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-76
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:1867)
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.camera.Camera.access$3100(Camera.java:87)
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.camera.Camera$5.run(Camera.java:1112)
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:1864)
03-15 03:31:15.922: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  ... 3 more
```

What is causing this error?  How can I best troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you able to resolve this?

Comment: @ManirajSS I don't think I could.