# Android emulator web cam is not detected

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, webcam, barcode-scanner

I am new to android development. I am creating Scandit barcode scanner application which is using android emulator's camera (webcam).

I have configured camera permissions related stuffs in `AndroidManifest.xml` file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="AndroidDemo.AndroidDemo" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <application android:label="AndroidDemo"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</manifest>
```

Now the logcat showing the following error:

```
07-21 13:21:03.026 E/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(   63): queryStart: Query failed: Cannot start the camera
07-21 13:21:03.026 E/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(   63): startDevice: Unable to start device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' for NV21[640x480] frames
```

Initially it was working fine.now i didnt change any code but it is not working. The camera functionality is randomly working.I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

And my emulator config is given below(visual studio):

[image: Emulator Config on Visual studio]

[And related question is not answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424606/android-error-using-webcam-in-emulator)

Thanks.

Comment: try changing the skin to WVGA800 or some of them to see if there is still the same problem

Comment: @JorgeCasariego actually what skin option will do? I dont know what it does mean by WVGA800 or QVGA .

Comment: Right now you have QVGA, change that for another

Comment: Im getting "Cant connect to the android wear app on your phone" error on my emulator for WVGA800. @JorgeCasariego