# How to use a PC webcam as the emulator's camera

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, android-virtual-device

I'm developing a qr code reader application. How can I use my webcam as a camera to scan the qr code in the emulator ?

my SDK version is 4.3. I checked it out in developer.android site and they said that you have to select webcam0 as a back camera. I tried but it didn't work, and shows "unfortunately your app has been stopped".

Answer (score 6):

Follow the below steps in Eclipse.

1. Goto -> AVD Manager
2. Create/Edit the AVD.
3. Hardware > New:
4. Configures camera facing back
5. Click on the property value and choose = "webcam0".
6. Once done all the above the webcam should be connected. If it doesnt
   then you need to check your WebCam drivers.

check this answer for the image & a further link:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14120794/1932105)

Comment: I'm using windows and my AVD Manager doesn't have an option call "Hardware" it has only backcamera and frontcamera and selected the webcam0 as backcamera.still it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, once you choose the emulator type (phone) the back/front are being enabled for options. then u choose webcam0 and it will work.

Comment: No..when i click the camera in emulator it says "unfortunately your app has been stopped"..I don't know why...I'm using 4.3 version emulator

Comment: can you post the logcat ?

Comment: Sorry..I'm new to this site...it says i need 10 reputations to add image..the logcat error is "Camera error 100"

Answer (score 6):

Use the Camera tab in Extended controls to add or modify Scene images. There are two image locations, one on the wall and one on the table.

To view these image locations in the scene, launch your emulator, then move the camera to the dining room area through the door behind the camera’s starting position.
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator#add_augmented_images_to_the_scene

Sample image from my emulator:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Android Studio virtual emulator now has virtual scene images under the camera section of the extended controls.  With this you add any image to be scanned by the virtual emulator.  Had a little trouble finding it though as you have to navigate into a different room to see it in the virtual scene. 
[Can't see virtual scene images in emulator camera app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477634/cant-see-virtual-scene-images-in-emulator-camera-app)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set front/Back cameras when you created the emulator like this in your AVD manager[image]

Comment: have you tried debugging into the code and see if their was anything wrong

Comment: yes..I'm running that app in version 4.3 mobile.it works properly.but i just need to scan the qr using emulator.