# Can't see virtual scene images in emulator camera app

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-camera

I'm using the Android Emulator (version 28.0.23-5264690) to develop an app that uses QR codes. The Virtual Scene feature for the camera on the emulator has an option to add your own images to the scene:

> > When using the emulator with a camera app, you can import an image in PNG or JPEG format to be used within a virtual scene. To choose an image for use in a virtual scene, click Add image in the Camera -> Virtual scene images tab in the Extended controls dialog.
> >
> > This feature can be used to import custom images such as QR codes for use with any camera-based app.

However, I've tried adding both JPG's and PNG's in the Emulator settings, but they never show up in the virtual scene in either the stock camera app or my own app. I've tried restarting the emulator as well, but still no luck.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I just found this piece of text at [the Android emulator documentation for augmented reality](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator#add_augmented_images_to_the_scene):

> To view these image locations in the scene, launch your emulator, then move the camera to the dining room area through the door behind the camera’s starting position.

So apparently the images show up in a different room than the one you start out in. By using the movement commands described in the link above, you have to walk into the "dining room", which is through the door behind the dog. There the images are displayed on the wall and the table.

Sadly, [the QR code scanner Flutter library I'm using](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan) doesn't respond to the QR code, so I'm stuck on using a physical device anyway.

Comment: yeah i've also been trying with a qr code reader but it doesn't recognize the image probably because of the angle you are forced to focus from

Comment: use alt + e to change the angle

Comment: I was having trouble with "walking to the dining room".. [here's the command](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator#move_the_virtual_camera) for you to "walk around"

Comment: Not so intuitive at all. But it works

Comment: Yes, angle is one thing, but let me drop 2 cents here regarging the flutter QR Code scanner (I am doing exactly same thing). I use this one (in case someone else wanders in here) https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner