# Android studio's emulator has an error "can't connect to camera"

Tags: android-studio

I'm connecting a webcam to my emulator by setting the front camera to "webcam0" in the AVD Manager.
When I launch the webcam from Android studio's AVD manager or using emulator -camera-front webcam0 , I get the following window:
[image]

and when the emulator has showed that is an error
[image]

Please help me how to fix that.

Comment: try selecting camera as Emulated. and let me know if that woks?

Comment: It's work :) thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: But I want to test with my notebook's camera. How can I fix it :(

Comment: what are you using emulator or device ? that solution i have given is for emulator's camera.

Comment: I use Nexus5. @Sushrita

Comment: Did the above solution work?

Comment: Yes,that's work :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to using your webcam? The emulated camera is useless to me, I need my laptop's webcam and it just doesn't want to connect.

Answer (score 16):

Go to Android Virtual device manager>>select the emulator>>click edit>>select Advanced Setting>>camera select as Emulated rather than Webcam0 .

Comment: To find the Android Virtual device manager in Android Studio: Tools > Android > AVD Manager

Comment: I do need to use Webcam0

Answer (score 7):

I got this error on new android emulator and was able to fix it by selecting *emulated* options for both Front and Back camera and clearing `Camera App's` **Cache** & **data**.

Comment: Rebooting device as well is often necessary

Comment: Clear app data did it for me, thx for the answer, i'm still having the error always when i switch to the front cam on this emulator, which is set to "emulated"

Comment: it is work for react native apps , thanks

Answer (score 4):

The solution for me was : " start Android Studio via command line vs starting it the usual way " Doing so makes Webcam0 work inside the emulator. 
On my Mac I simply typed

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```

into terminal. I also used Automator later to create a workflow which runs the script (command above), and saved the workflow as an app.

Using such Android Studio launcher.app launches Android Studio.app for me via command line.

Answer (score 3):

> Android Studio:
>   **Tools** > **AVD Manager**

[image]

> select the **Device** & click edit

[image]

> click **Show Advanced Setting**

[image]

> Camera select as  **Webcam0**

[image]

Click >> **Finish**

Answer (score 0):

Download the free personal use version of [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) and use that emulator instead of the one that come with Android Studio.

Like you, I've been trying all morning to make my webcam work with the emulator that comes with android studio without success. 0 problems with genymotion so far.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just change `configuration -> saved -> turn on device (cold boot notification will appear) -> then turn off device -> revert change -> turn on again`.

I don't know but it works for me. Maybe it just cache problem. CMIIW.

Answer (score -1):

but if you are using bluestack emulator or any  other emulator.
then in emulator first open emulator camera then click photo of that 
then again your own application  in emulator and click button of camera ..i must be work ..