# Android Mobile "Camera Can't Connect" Error?

Tags: android, mobile-application, mobile-phones, mobile-devices, mobile-development

I am unable to access my camera application on my android mobile Micromax A250. Whenever I'm opening the app it is displaying me the errors:

1. Can't Connect Camera
2. Gallery Has Stopped

Please resolve my query and provide me solution how can I access my camera application.

Answer (score 0):

that is may be a run time permission ,can you please refer the link,https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Thanks @Vadivel for your help but this isn't resolving my issue. The problem is not with the app permission. Earlier this issue was resolved when I "Force Stop" the application, but this time it is not working. May be this information will help you to resolve my issue.

Comment: Reported. Rebooting is a lethal death sin.

Answer (score 0):

Look my links hope it helps:

1. If emulator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36904976/5241603
2. If Real Device: http://www.howtodroid.com/2016/04/cant-connect-camera-error-android.html (I haven't read it yet too.)
3. Check permission Camera and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your code.