# Android emulator face recognition

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

Is there any way to test android face recognition provided by `BiometricPrompt` on an emulator?

I know of the command:

> adb -e emu finger touch

but this is only for fingerprint authentication.

Comment: Usually the Native Emulator of android studio does not access the Webcam on your PC, I have done this with a small workaround but it will take some extra time, get a android EMU like Bluestacks or Nox and run your app on that and test it that way

Comment: What were the Android devices that supported Face recognition. Just curious. @RubenMeiring

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? @AdamN

Comment: @Rohit Singh My kind company bought device with face recognition (Pixel 4) for my team and this was the solution for me :)

Comment: @RohitSingh It depends if the manufacturer of the device has implemented it,
As AdamN said the Google "Pixel 4"  has it and then Samsung from about the S8 and up has it, Facial recognition has been in android since about Android 4.0 Ice Cream, But it depends if the manufacturer has implemented it

Answer (score 2):

You could connect your webcam to your emulator to test the face recognition. Try following the steps in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792615/7703505