# Android Studio is not able to run webcam on macOS systems

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, camera, capacitor

In android studio for macOS systems, I'm trying to run an app that use the mobile camera.

When I run the app with a virtual device, all works fine, but when I click on the button that starts the camera, my app crashes.

I'm surelly the problem is that I have to give permissions to Android Studio for use the webcam of my computer, but I dont have any notification for it and if I try to add this permission manually in the system configuration menu (System preferences --> Security & privacity --> Privacity --> Camera), I dont find any option to add any new application.

Do you know if I can allow use the camera to any new application manually? Or if the Android Studio problem is any other?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Same problem here!!

Comment: This worked fine for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30792615/5524175. I'm on 13.5.1 with Apple M1 Pro chip.