# How can I use webcam camera in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, webcam

I would like to use my webcam in the android camera.

I've checked out this stack overflow post: [Android: How to use webcam in emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012924/android-how-to-use-webcam-in-emulator) but when I complete the steps in the accepted answer...

I keep getting the error, "**Camera keeps crashing**."

In my Manifest file, I've declared the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.front"/>
```

Any idea why the camera keeps crashing?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

After doing lots of research,

I found out that android simply required a reboot. If this doesn't work for anyone else, try deleting your emulator and re-installing it.