# capture video using android emulator and webcam

Tags: android

I am using webcam for capturing video in android emulator, is the webcam is enough for capturing the video using android emulator?

Comment: Follow this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image

Comment: Newly created android emulator version 2.2 using AVD Manager with sdcard size of 50MiB.