# Android Virtual Device camera is not working despite I have chosen webcam as a source

Tags: android, android-camera, android-virtual-device

I have Acer Aspire V3-571G which has integrated web camera in it. It is working I checked it.

1.In AVD setup I have chose Webcam0 as a source.

2.When started an emulator it asked me for selecting the source I chose hdWebCam.

3.When started camera in the emulator I still get werid emulated(?) screen. How to fix it?

**Images in correct order below.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [THIS?][1]  Looks like it should be what you're looking for.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276450/how-to-use-web-camera-in-android-emulator-to-capture-a-live-image

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same results as you until I changed the processor type to Intel, from MIPS.  My webcam came on for a few seconds but then the camera app crashed in the emulator.  I am using a Mac.  You should try changing the processor type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value of VM heap in memory option for this one. Like this:

> VM heap : 32