# Syntax error on token "}" error appears

Tags: android, eclipse, syntax, token

I getting this error "Syntax error on token "}", delete this token." on the last line and I don't know why as I am new to Android.

```
   public void ok() throws UiObjectNotFoundException{
            //trying to find ok
                   try{
                       UiObject okDialog = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("ok"));
                   if(okDialog.exists()){
                       System.out.println("Success");   
                       break;//if ok exists it should come out
                   }
                   //if ok not exists
                   if(!okDialog.exists()){
                         System.out.println("retrying");
                         getUiDevice().pressHome();
                         UiObject enterButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("enter"));
                         enterButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();  
                   }
                   //validating again to check ok exists
                   if(okDialog.exists())
                         break;
                   else   //if ok not exists again printing the belwo message
                         System.out.println("unable to find"); 
                         getUiDevice().pressHome();
    //Here if ok not exists after going to home, i want to stop the whole script here..how to do this?
                   }catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {}

                   }
    } Error message appears here : Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

Comment: Are you developer ???

Comment: remove last "}" from your code. or check perfectly your whole class.

Comment: I just started learning.

Comment: if i delete the last "}" from code, "break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch" error appears wherever the "break" is there in the code

Comment: @CapDroid Can your answer my this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715655/camera-of-any-emulator-not-working

Comment: Don't need any { in If conditions }

Comment: @user3089474 , You can't add break in if condition, you need to `return` instead of `break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have know just English knowledge, then you can eazly delete this } in shown your error message side

> You can't add break in if condition, you need to return instead of break and remove {} in if conditions

```
} Error message appears here : Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

Copy past this code instead of your method

```
  public void ok() throws  UiObjectNotFoundException
{
        //trying to find ok
               try{

                   UiObject okDialog = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("ok"));

                   if(okDialog.exists())
                   System.out.println("Success");   
                   return;//if ok exists it should come out


               //if ok not exists
               if(!okDialog.exists())
                     System.out.println("retrying");
                     getUiDevice().pressHome();
                     UiObject enterButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("enter"));
                     enterButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();  


               //validating again to check ok exists
               if(okDialog.exists())
                     return;
               else   //if ok not exists again printing the belwo message
                     System.out.println("unable to find"); 
                     getUiDevice().pressHome();
//Here if ok not exists after going to home, i want to stop the whole script here..how to do this?
               }
catch (UiObjectNotFoundExceptione) {}

               }
```

Comment: for a method signature, use **throws** not **throw**.

public void ok() **throws** UiObjectNotFoundException is correct one

Comment: Yep sorry about that \

Comment: you cant use break in if condition.

Comment: I have update my answer, Please take a look

Comment: Hey Ramesh Rajendran, it is working fine:)....i want to stop the script when "validating again to check ok exists" it should go home then script should not proceed further.

Comment: If my code was work, please put mark as answer, It's helps other :)

Comment: Can you please help out how to stop the script proceeding further when validation fails in the code //validating again to check ok exists.

Comment: I think this question should be closed for too many minus vote. So you need to ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are missing closing brackets (}) some where in your code. That's why you are getting this error. Have a close look at your code. and you will find solution.

Comment: Are you sure he is missing ?

Comment: @GrIsHu, Yes i am sure by looking at this code. because after catch block he just need to close only one bracket but he tries to close two brackets. You can have a look at his code.

Comment: That is what i said the last bracket is an extra that is why he need to delete it ,not to add any extra bracket. @Innocent Killer

Answer (score 0):

The last bracket is unnecessary so delete that bracket.

The error itself indicates to remove the last bracket `}`

```
  } Error message appears here : Syntax error on token "}", delete this token
```

If you get error `"break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch"`

Then change your if condition as below:

```
      if(!okDialog.exists())
               System.out.println("unable to find"); 
                getUiDevice().pressHome();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
}catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e){}
}
```

change to

```
}catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e){
}
```

notice that you closed right away the opening bracket after your catch

Comment: Still the syntax error "{" appears

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void ok() throws UiObjectNotFoundException{
            //trying to find ok
                   try{
                       UiObject okDialog = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("ok"));
                   if(okDialog.exists()){
                       System.out.println("Success");   
                       break;//if ok exists it should come out
                   }
                   //if ok not exists
                   if(!okDialog.exists()){
                         System.out.println("retrying");
                         getUiDevice().pressHome();
                         UiObject enterButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("enter"));
                         enterButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();  
                   }
                   //validating again to check ok exists
                   if(okDialog.exists()){
                         //break;
                   }
                   else  {
                         //if ok not exists again printing the belwo message
                         System.out.println("unable to find"); 
                         getUiDevice().pressHome();
                   }
    //Here if ok not exists after going to home, i want to stop the whole script here..how to do this?
                   }catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {}    

    }
```

Comment: i tried out.."break cannot be used outside of a loop or a switch" error appears wherever the "break" is there in the code

Comment: see I have commented this break in my answer. Break cant be used in if condition Thats why you are getting this error. @user3089474