# Camera shows black in Android emulator

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I written an app to show the camera and potentially do barcode scans. The camera view is just black. Any idea what could be the issue? There are no errors though the camera still doesn't show. The view is just plain black. I added the option to move the camera to my computer camera in the emulator, and when opening the app the little light near the camera in my computer turns on, so it seems it is working. Adding here the code of a mini project I created to reproduce the problem without extra noise:

Java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CameraSelector cameraSelector;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProvider;
    private ProcessCameraProvider processCameraProvider;
    private Preview cameraPreview;
    private ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            String[] cameraPermission = new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, cameraPermission, 0);
        }
        findViewById(R.id.btn_start_camera).setOnClickListener(v ->
                initBarcodeScanner(findViewById(R.id.camera_preview)));
    }

    private void initBarcodeScanner(PreviewView previewView) {
        cameraSelector = new CameraSelector
                .Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                .build();
        cameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);

        cameraProvider.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                processCameraProvider = cameraProvider.get();
                cameraPreview = new Preview
                        .Builder()
                        .build();
                cameraPreview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

                BarcodeScanner barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient(
                        new BarcodeScannerOptions
                                .Builder()
                                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS)
                                .build()
                );
                imageAnalysis = new ImageAnalysis
                        .Builder()
                        .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
                        .build();

                ExecutorService cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

                imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, imageProxy ->
                        processImageProxy(barcodeScanner, imageProxy));

                processCameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis);

            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }


    @OptIn(markerClass = ExperimentalGetImage.class)
    private void processImageProxy(BarcodeScanner barcodeScanner, ImageProxy imageProxy) {
        if (imageProxy.getImage() != null) {
            InputImage inputImage = InputImage
                    .fromMediaImage(
                            imageProxy.getImage(),
                            imageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees()
                    );
            barcodeScanner
                    .process(inputImage)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(barcodes -> {
                        if (!barcodes.isEmpty()) {
                            // todo handle barcodes read
                            Toast.makeText(this, barcodes.get(0).getDisplayValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(Throwable::printStackTrace)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(results -> imageProxy.close());
        }
    }

}
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_start_camera"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="start camera" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Gradle Dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.9.10"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the emulator does not support the camera. How should this work if the smartphone is not connected to the PC and the PC itself does not have a webcam?

But there can be partial solutions, as has been discussed on StackOverflow in the question [Camera of any emulator not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20715655/) extensively before.

See also the short article [Camera support](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-use-camera#:%7E:text=When%20using%20the%20emulator%20with,tab%2C%20and%20click%20Add%20image.) on developer.android.com.